# Python : How to write list to csv with N items per row

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to save list to csv. My code like this :

```
import csv
list = ['John Doe', '51234512214', 'California', 'Student', 'Jane Doe', '1234123123', 'Canada', 'Student', 'Bill Gates', '4123123123211', 'New York', 'Student']

with open(export_file, 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(list)
myfile.close()
```

**Question**

I want to create csv from list 4 items per row. My excepted csv output is like this :

[image]

How to achieve my expected csv file with best python approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can first make a function to yield n sized chunks:

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
```

Then write each chunk from the generator to a CSV file:

```
with open("output.csv", mode="w", newline="") as csv_out:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_out, quoting=QUOTE_ALL)
    for chunk in chunks(lst, 4):
        csv_writer.writerow(chunk)
```

**Full Code:**

```
from csv import writer, QUOTE_ALL

lst = [
    "John Doe",
    "51234512214",
    "California",
    "Student",
    "Jane Doe",
    "1234123123",
    "Canada",
    "Student",
    "Bill Gates",
    "4123123123211",
    "New York",
    "Student",
]

def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

with open("output.csv", mode="w", newline="") as csv_out:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_out, quoting=QUOTE_ALL)
    for chunk in chunks(lst, 4):
        csv_writer.writerow(chunk)
```

**output.csv:**

```
"John Doe","51234512214","California","Student"
"Jane Doe","1234123123","Canada","Student"
"Bill Gates","4123123123211","New York","Student"
```

Comment: Could also use `for chunk in zip(*[iter(lst)]*4):` which would not require the `chunks()` helper function. Still a a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the original list in sublists of 4 items, and write it as once using `writerows`:

```
import csv
data = ['John Doe', '51234512214', 'California', 'Student', 'Jane Doe', '1234123123', 'Canada', 'Student', 'Bill Gates', '4123123123211', 'New York', 'Student']
rows = [data[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]

with open(export_file, 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerows(rows)
```

Note a few additional changes:

- I changed the name of your original list from `list` to `data`: you shouldn't use the name of Python builtins as variable names (here, you would be prevented from using `list` to build lists further on)
- You have to open the file in text mode (the default), not binary, as you did by using `'wb'`.
- I added the `newline=''` argument. As stated at the very end of the `csv` module documentation:

> If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields
>   will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n
>   linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be
>   safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own
>   (universal) newline handling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the oneliner

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

your_list = ['John Doe', '51234512214', 'California', 'Student', 'Jane Doe', '1234123123', 'Canada', 'Student', 'Bill Gates', '4123123123211', 'New York', 'Student']

pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.array(your_list), (int(len(your_list)/4), 4))).to_csv('your_list_as.csv', index = False, header = False)
```